# Node js route need to wait for processing of another request

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, httprequest

We processing the order requests, on the time of multiple HTTP requests hitting the same route function means the function not working properly

Actually, we write the async await operation for all DB related queries

our coding example is

```
buyCtrl.orderPlace = async function (req, res, next) {
    var response = await table1.find({exchange:ref_m}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
    if(response.length > 0)
    {
        var incRes = await table2.findOneAndUpdate({_id:1},{a:b}, {new: true});
        var OrdersIns          = new Orders();
        OrdersIns.userid       = userid;
        OrdersIns.from         = 'a';
        OrdersIns.to           = 'b';
        await OrdersIns.save();
        await compare(positiondetails[0]);
        res.status(200).json({status:true,message:'Order placed successfully'});

    }
}
const compare = async (curOrder) => {
    var result = await Orders.find({userid:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid),type:opp}).sort({posTimestamp:1});
    if(result.length>0)
    {
        for(var pi=0;pi<result.length;pi++)
        {
            if(parseFloat(curOrder.qty)==parseFloat(result[i].qty))
            {
                var updatedata = {a:b}
                await Orders.findOneAndUpdate({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(curOrder._id)}, updatedata, {new: true});
                await Orders.remove({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result[i]._id)});
            }
            else 
            {
                var updatedata = {a:b}
                await Orders.findOneAndUpdate({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result[i]._id))}, updatedata, {new: true});
                await Orders.remove({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(curOrder._id)});
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This is the flow we have I cannot paste my full code so make some example code
Please check and share your ideas
when we make an automation test with more concurrent requests the compare and update is not working properly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For atomic operations such as increment and decrement, this can be done using MongoDB's provided API. Another solution is to work with versioning, which MongoDB provides out of the box. The concurrent connection might update the object which changed before the update could take place.